# Select Last Links on Page with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have an HTML page that has some links in the footer. I need to dynamically change the class applied to those links via JQuery. For instance, I need to set the link classes to a class named "footerToggled".

```
...

<footer>
  <div>  
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <a href="/Site/">Home</a> 
        <a href="/Site/Contact">Contact Us</a> 
        <a href="/Site/About">About Us</a> 
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</footer>
```

How do I set the CSS class applied to the anchor tags within the nav element within the footer of my pag VIA JQuery?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What you mean by ***Last Links***?? do you need to add class to the last `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('footer div nav ul a').addClass('footerToggled');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RQLyh/1/

Comment: What if there is a table element within my DIV that holds the NAV element within a table cell? I don't understand how these selectors work.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('footer nav a').addClass('footerToggled' )
```

But you should use classes / id's in your markup, and use a valid one by the way - you need to fill your `<ul>` with `<li>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to ***Select Last Links on Page*** 
 to use [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

To add a `css` class use [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

So for an example

```
$('footer nav a').last().addClass('footerToggled');
```

If you need to style all the `<a>` in footer

```
$('footer a').addClass('footerToggled')
```